# how to populate a mongoDb documents from another collections with unique Ids

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I am trying to populate documents from another collection into the documents that is meant to be returned. E.g

```
{
  msg:"success",
  data:[
      {
        _id: "61d97498dc11d6d80db7212e",
        feedbackTitle: "Testing",
        comment:[
            { 
              _id: "61d974e0dc11d6d80db7213b",
              sender: "61d87a94b43d99126841187d",
              subcomment:[
                    {
                       content: "This is my first subcomment",
                       sender: {
                           _id: "61d713dd0e5ff818f6701345",
                            name: "bamigboye",
                            email: "bamigboye@gmail.com",
                            pic: "/uploads/Battery.PNG"
                            },
                        owner: {
                            _id: "61d87a94b43d99126841187d",
                            name: "titi",
                            email: "titi@gmail.com",
                            pic: "/uploads/Battery.PNG"
                           },
                         _id: "61d97c96af284a97b3bb557a",
                    }
                 ]
            }
          ],
      }
  ]
}
```

am able to join and populate the above objects with this code here

```
const feedbacks = await Feedback.find({})
    .populate("user", "_id name pic email")
    .populate({
      path: "comment",
      populate: {
        path: "sender",
        model: "User",
        select: "_id name pic email",
      },
      populate: [
        {
          path: "subcomment",
          populate: {
            path: "sender owner",
            model: "User",
            select: "_id name pic email",
          },
        },
      ],
    });
    

  res.status(StatusCodes.OK).json({ msg: "success", data: feedbacks });
```

now the problem I have right now is that, inside the comment array above, the sender property value is not being populated and whereas I did populate it according to the code above, I read in mongoose docs about a scenario like this, that it only the second query that will be effected but am totally new to the backend world coming from the frontend world and I have no idea how to structure my code in a scenario like these for the comment.sender to be populated.

Answer (score 0):

After so many debugging and reading on how to join same path with different properties, I read the [mongoose docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) `populating multiple paths` and received an insight of how to go about it. so I interchanged the way have chained the populate path placing the user populate between two same path and it worked.

```
const feedbacks = await Feedback.find({})
.populate({
  path: "comment",
  populate: {
    path: "sender",
    model: "User",
    select: "_id name pic email",
  },
})
.populate({ path: "user", select: "_id name email pic" })
.populate({
  path: "comment",
  populate: [
    {
      path: "subcomment",
      populate: {
        path: "sender owner",
        model: "User",
        select: "_id name pic email",
      },
    },
  ],
});res.status(StatusCodes.OK).json({ msg: "success", data: feedbacks });
```